# plotting pandas points with different colors

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

I have a pandas data frame of two columns ['frequency','color'] and it looks like this:

```
 name  frequency  color
0   351   r
1   122   r
2   30    g
3   85    r
4   195   r
5   88    g
6   130   r
7   85    r
8   41    r
9   9     g
```

I want to plot the 'frequency' sorted and depending on the colors. I tried this:

```
plt.scatter(y=np.sort(data['frequency']),x=range(len(data['frequency'])),c=np.sort(data['color']))
```

and i got the following error:

> ValueError: to_rgba: Invalid rgba arg "['r']" to_rgb: Invalid rgb arg
>   "('r',)" sequence length is 1; must be 3 or 4

what is wrong in the code?

Comment: Your code ran without error for me.

Comment: did the colors, red and green, appear?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following figure
[image]

is produced by this code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

frequency = [351,122,30,85,195,88,130,85,41,9]
color = ["r","r","g","r","r","g","r","r","r","g"]
df = pd.DataFrame( {"frequency" : frequency, "color" : color})
df.sort_values("frequency", inplace=True)

plt.scatter(x=range(len(df)), y= df["frequency"], c = df["color"])
plt.show()
```